# Setting up ovpn connect for iPhone with no ovpn file

Tags: network-manager, iphone, openvpn

I have a working openvpn connection on a Ubuntu laptop. When I export it (using network-manager) I get a conf file. I need an ovpn file so I can configure my openvpn app on my iPhone. I also have a crt file which I used to configure my laptop with - if it's any help. Trying to send the conf file to via mail and import it yielded an error message about a missing crt file. Sending the crt file create a profile that I'm not aware how to use. We're using User/pass authentication so I won't be able to get a key and cert file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution (after consulting [this ovpn forum](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic12011.html) goes as follows:

1. export your config file from network manager.
2. save the .conf file as .ovpn.
3. To add ca, cert and key entries to the .ovpn file: 
    a. Use your admin supplied crt file and extract the ca there into your file. Add before and after `<ca> your cert chars here <ca/>`

   b. do the same for `<cert> random data </cert>` but use this for the data:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIB1jCCAT+gAwIBAgIEAmLSTjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAVMRMwEQYDVQQDEwpP cGVuVlBOIENBMB4XDTEzMDExNzAyMTExMloXDTIzMDEyMjAyMTExMlowKDEmMCQG A1UEAxQdZnJyaWN0aW9uQGdtYWlsLmNvbV9BVVRPTE9HSU4wgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcN AQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBALVEXIZYYu1Inmejuo4Si6Eo5AguTX5sg1pGbLkJSTR4 BXQsy6ocUnZ9py8htYkipkUUhjY7zDu+wJlUtWnVCwCYtewYfEc/+azH7+7eU6ue T2K2IKdik1KWhdtNbaNphVvSlgdyKiuZDTCedptgWyiL50N7FMcUUMjjXYh/hftB AgMBAAGjIDAeMAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwEQYJYIZIAYb4QgEBBAQDAgeAMA0GCSqGSIb3 DQEBBQUAA4GBABhVzSYXHlQEPNaKGmx9hMwwnNKcHgD9cCmC9lX/KR2Y+vT/QGxK 7sYlJInb/xmpa5TUQYc1nzDs9JBps1mCtZbYNNDpYnKINAKSDsM+KOQaSYQ2FhHk bmBZk/K96P7VntzYI5S02+hOWnvjq5Wk4gOt1+L18+R/XujuxGbwnHW2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

```
c. and for `<key> random key </key>` -  use this key:
```

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBALVEXIZYYu1Inmej uo4Si6Eo5AguTX5sg1pGbLkJSTR4BXQsy6ocUnZ9py8htYkipkUUhjY7zDu+wJlU tWnVCwCYtewYfEc/+azH7+7eU6ueT2K2IKdik1KWhdtNbaNphVvSlgdyKiuZDTCe dptgWyiL50N7FMcUUMjjXYh/hftBAgMBAAECgYEAsNjgOEYVRhEaUlzfzmpzhakC SKT8AALYaAPbYO+ZVzJdh8mIbg+xuF7A9G+7z+5ZL35lrpXKnONuvmlxkK5ESwvV Q7EOQYCZCqa8xf3li3GUBLwcwXKtOUr3AYXhdbOh2viQdisD4Ky7H6/Nd3yMc3bu R4pErmWeHei+l6dIwAECQQDqljNxi9babmHiei6lHaznCMg5+jfAyDXgHvO/afFr 1bDQVDTDK+64kax4E9pvDZC6B/HGse9hOUGWXTjb0WZBAkEAxdAw/14iJIUcE5sz HDy2R0RmbUQYFjrNgBCi5tnmr1Ay1zHAs1VEF+Rg5IOtCBO50I9jm4WCSwCtN6zF FoFVAQJAUGfBJDcZIm9ZL6ZPXJrqS5oP/wdLmtFE3hfd1gr7C8oHu7BREWB6h1qu 8c1kPlI4+/qDHWaZtQpJ977mIToJwQJAMcgUHKAm/YPWLgT31tpckRDgqgzh9u4z e1A0ft5FlMcdFFT8BuWlblHWJIwSxp6YO6lqSuBNiuyPqxw6uVAxAQJAWGxOgn2I fGkWLLw4WMpkFHmwDVTQVwhTpmMP8rWGYEdYX+k9HeOJyVMrJKg2ZPXOPtybrw8T PUZE7FgzVNxypQ==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

1. Mail the file to yourself and open it in the native mail app.
2. The file should be marked with the OVPN symbol - use it, it will open the ovpn app and import it
3. Add user name and password.
4. Press the off button -> phone should try to connect...
5. Enjoy

Comment: Looks like the linked board post does not exist